# Which gameloop method for custom OpenGL- ES code when using SpriteKit

Tags: ios, opengl-es, sprite-kit

Because of some unique map needs I may have to render my own background tiles rather than let SpriteKit do it. In the java version we have our own custom `update`/`render` methods in which we draw everything to opengl.

However, SpriteKit doesn't seem to expose a `render` method, so I'm trying to determine the best game-loop method for our custom rendering to occur in. As far as I can tell, the `update` method is the only gameloop method SpriteKit exposes.

Comment: There's no direct OpenGL access but you can easily create a tilemap renderer using just sprites. See Kobold Kit for an example implementation: https://github.com/KoboldKit/KoboldKit/blob/master/KoboldKit/KoboldKitFree/Framework/Nodes/Tilemap/KKTilemapTileLayerNode.m

Answer (score 0):

Sprite Kit does not allow direct access to OpenGL so far. It is intended to be simple engine for beginners.

Comment: Does cocos2d? I'd like to have something manage the gameloop and scene/frame but I just need to do some custom texture rendering.